# Products are not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, frontend

I have made a trial magento site http://abhimanu.colourentice.com/magento and added some products from the backend. I had tried every possible solution on many sites but the problem does not solved "Enabled, Quantity and In stock". Is there anything i can do for it? I am new to magento and looking for some help.

Comment: Can you select categories in product? if not than select catagories n search product name you will get product

Comment: Yes, i have selected category in product.

Comment: can you give me your admin url?

Comment: Here is the login page for Admin. http://abhimanu.colourentice.com/magento/index.php/admin

Comment: your problem is when you search your product it was redirect to http://abhimanu.colourentice.com/magento/catalogsearch/result/?q=flower but actually it should be redirect to this page - http://abhimanu.colourentice.com/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=flower

Comment: [Try this](http://brijesh-on-magento.blogspot.in/2011/12/search-on-frontend-not-working.html) hope this will help you if not then update your question

Comment: Solved please check it. change this only to solve problem **System > Configuration >Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites turn off**

Comment: do i need to change  Use Web Server Rewrites turn off to YES??

Comment: Please you can anything you want in the admin panel but the product should be how in the home page and link should work. I've tried the best i could but i am unable to solve this problem.

Comment: Somehow i have manage to make the links work correctly but still products are not showing on homepage. Any Suggestions??

Comment: you need to set **Use Web Server Rewrites** as NO

Comment: Check it..I'm added code in admin **CMS->Manage pages->Homepage -> content** {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}. All Product are showning in home page

Answer (score 1):

As i have checked your site i found there is no category there.

So first of all **create category** if you have not created and if already created category than select "Yes" option for navigation menu and make it enable.
After that select appropriate category from product.

You need to specify one **root category** for your store in "System > Manage Stores" and add the first level categories of your store below this.

After doing above thing if you don't find product than also check it **assigned to the website** if you have multiple websites.

Comment: for my category i have selected Is active = yes and Include in navigation menu = yes.

Comment: have you checked the visibility of product that its set to 'catalog/search'?

Comment: Yes, the visibility of the product is set to catalog/search.

Answer (score 0):

Add categories (Admin Panel -> Catalog -> Manage categories) and then assign products in that category.
Then you'll be able to see the products by selecting and visiting those categories.

Comment: I had already assigned my products to the category but still no visibility.